# What is the correct way to unit test a pickle file using pytest?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, pickle, python-unittest

I have written a unit test case for a function in my project which particularly opens a pickle file- dumps and then closes it.
here is the function:- app.py

```
def data_serialization():
    global dlp_instance
    file_pi = open('App-backup.pickle', "wb")
    pickle.dump(dlp_instance, file_pi)
    file_pi.close()
```

and here is the unit test case which I've written to the function.:- test_app.py

```
class TestDlp(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        application.testing = True
        self.client = application.test_client()
    
    def test_data_serialization(self):
        from dlp.dlp import data_serialization
        read_data = pickle.dumps({'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3})
        mock_open = mock.mock_open(read_data=read_data)
        with patch('dlp.dlp.data_serialization', mock_open):
            obj = data_serialization()
        self.assertFalse(obj)
        self.assertNotEqual({'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}, obj)
```

The testcase runs successfully. In addition to it, I have also written a secondary testcase by referring to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44608345/14405051

```
    def test_data_ser(self):
        import builtins
        builtins.open = open = Mock()
        open.return_value = sio = StringIO()
        self.client.save('App-backupsss.pickle')
        new_data = pickle.load(sio.getvalue())
        self.assertEqual(self.client, new_data)
```

However this testcase gave me an attribute error stating that 'FlaskClient' object has no attribute 'save'.

So, in this scenario what is the correct way of writing a unit test case for pickle files?

**EDIT**:- Since the above two testcases were actually Incorrect here's what I tried.

```
@mock.patch("builtins.open")
    def test_data_cerial(self, mock_open):
        from dlp.dlp import data_serialization
        data_serialization()
        self.assertEqual(mock_open.call_count, 1)
```

And this runs successfully.

Comment: Why _would_ a `FlaskClient` object have a `.save()` function? Why are you calling it?

Comment: @AKX even I thought so. Is the unit test case which passed succesfully correct? Or is there any other way of writing it correctly?

Comment: Well, if I'm reading things right, you're basically replacing the `data_serialization()` function altogether, so you're not testing it. Look at the test coverage for that function and test to make sure you're testing the right thing.

Comment: @AKX you are right! The function is not being tested. Could you please help me understand a bit more as to how do i write it correcly. I was already not sure if it was right and now that it's not testing is making things even more complicated for me.

Comment: You should probably first figure out what you're testing here :)

Comment: @AKX yes I've already figured that out..so all i want to test is whether the pickle file opens and closes.

Comment: You'll probably want something with `with patch('app.open', mock.mock_open(...)):` to just mock out the open call.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223620/discussion-between-curious-guy-and-akx).